# How to find in one sheet in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

When I try to search something in Numbers, it will find in all sheets. Is it possible to search in currently selected sheet only?

MacBook Air macOS Sierra 10.12.3, Numbers 4.0.5

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Yeah, I'm not sure this is possible. I've even stumbled across my own answer looking for a solution myself.

Open the sheet and use Find & Replace.

Command-F or Edit -> Find -> Find...

For *most* Apple productivity apps, Command-F can be used to find text in that app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew `cmd-f` could search. The problem is, this search will search in all my sheets. Since the data is quite large, I would like to narrow down to a specific sheet ONLL, not all sheets.

Comment: By the way, Excel default search on the current sheet.

Comment: Yeah this did not answer the question. I am having the same issue. How to search in ONE SHEET only, out of the multiple sheets.